# Use C with Android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to develop a Android project that makes a simple call from Java code to native C code.
I refer this link for my guidance: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

when I am compiling the native.c 
using

```
:ndk-build
```

it shows:

```
ndk-build command not found
```

Could anyone give the reason for this?

thanks ,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question description, i assume that your path is not set. You need to set your NDK path in your environment variable.

for more information you can visit following site.

- http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html
- http://code.google.com/p/awesomeguy/wiki/JNITutorial#Unpack_Android_NDK
- [How to install and Build NDK with eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407224/how-to-install-and-build-ndk-with-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

From my part, I try to set the path by several ways:

- complete the /etc/paths file with the ndk directory and restart the Mac
- use the shell command: `export NDK_HOME=/Users/myself/directory1/directory2/android-ndk-r9`
- use the Eclipse menu: Eclipse > Preferences > Android > NDK

However I always get the error message: "ndk-build command not found"

Finally I solved the issue by setting the path directly in the Build command field of the C/C++ Build Properties dialog box: */Users/myself/directory1/directory2/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build*
I know it's not a proper solution but it works for me for now.