# How to load native library on android?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, native

I've got a .so library, which I've extracted from an other APK.

I've copied it into /libs/armeabi location in my project.

In my class, I'm loading it with

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylib"); 
}
```

The app crashes with

```
08-03 07:52:08.089: E/AndroidRuntime(932): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mylib: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
at com.example.mytestandroidapp.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:11)
08-03 07:52:08.089: E/AndroidRuntime(932):  ... 15 more
```

I'm doing this in eclipse.

Here's the screen of the layout of my project:

[image]

What should I do for this to start working?

Comment: why screenshot ? upload the code, it will help better.

Comment: check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11753336/996493) help you out :)

Comment: your static block already show hint in comment line.

Comment: In addition to the `lib` prefix issue: are you running on emulator or on device? Is the run-time architecture really ARMEABI? Is the library's architecture really ARMEABI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"rename `mylib.so` in `libmylib.so`, and run your programm again (without modify the loadLibrary argument)" from blackbelt

+

The folder `libs/armeabi-v7a` should also contain the `libmylib.so` library. If your phone is a new one, he will check there for libraries.

Answer (score 3):

rename `mylib.so`  in `libmylib.so`, and run your programm again (without modify the loadLibrary argument)

Comment: Refresh and rebuild the project once you do that :) Also, open the APK with an archiver (rename to ZIP if necessary), make sure the library file is really there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the lib location path refer to:

> context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/lib"

and if you use API level 9, alternatively directly go to the lib directory with

> context.getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir