# ndk-build not found in Path

Tags: android, android-ndk

[image: android-ndk error]

I'm trying to setup ndk to work with in eclipse. I keep getting this message saying that ndk-build isn't found in path. I've added it to Environment Variables->Path but still not working.

Any help?!

Comment: you have mistake in your path , instead of `c:\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build` use `C:\android-ndk-r8e`

Answer (score 12):

Right click on your project , Go to Build Path->Select **Configure Build Path** -> Select **C/C++ Build**->Select **Builder Setting** Tab ->In **Builder Setting** set your ndk-build path i.e `C:\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build`.

Comment: still the same message appears again.

Comment: restart the eclipse once and then build again...

Answer (score 12):

The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825963/918535

//goto Preference  → Android → NDK and choose your ndk location

Comment: If that's really the answer to the question, then you should flag the question as a duplicate instead of answering it with just a link.

Comment: relax dude this is not the ans setting the ndk build path in preferences does not works lolz. . .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse for Windows try to link to ndk-build.cmd. It worked for me.