# ndk path can be set manually, but not automatically

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm trying to setup ndk to work with eclipse, but getting this error message 
`Program "/ndk-build.cmd" is not found in PATH`

Following other posts ([ndk-build not found in Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312311/ndk-build-not-found-in-path) , [Set Build path in Eclipse for ndk program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825534/set-build-path-in-eclipse-for-ndk-program)) I tried to set the NDK folder in preferences -> android -> NDK, but it did't work.

Next I tried to manually set the NDK folder in Build Path->Configure Build Path -> C/C++ Build->Builder Setting Tab -> ndk-build path for one specific project, and it worked, but I need to repeat this for all my projects one at a time.

Any idea how to set the path correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I've also suffered a lot with configuring the NDK in my eclipse. At last, this procedure was working for me (with eclipse helios):

1. Download `Eclipse NDK plugin` and `NDK` and configure it by

   **eclipse > windows > preference > android > NDK > configure NDK location**
2. Import a project which has native C++ codes and require NDK. After importing, it will say **Program "/ndk-build.cmd" is not found in PATH**
3. right click on the project, go to

   **new > other > C/C++ > convert to C/C++ > toolchains > android GCC > click finish**
4. Right click on the project and go to project property.

   **Property > C++ build > Environment**

   Create a variable named `NDK-BUILD` with your NDK location

   ---

   **Property > C++ build > Environment**

   In Builder Settings:
    put Build Command: `${NDK-BUILD}/ndk-build.cmd`

   In behavior:
    unchecked `Clean`

   ---

   Go to **Property > C/C++ general > Paths & symbols > Language > GNU C++**
   add a variable with path: `${NDK-BUILD}\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include`

Press apply & ok

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Method which worked for me is.

Goto the **Project Properties** 
Click on **C/C++ Build** (An other list will open) 
Click on the **Environment** from the list 
Now click on **Add**

Here you have to Put 2 values 
Put Name as **NDKROOT** 
In Value put **PATH TO THE NDK FOLDER** 
Then Click **OK**

[image]

That's It