# ndk-build.cmd command not found

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

While trying to develop Hello World NDK program on Ubuntu with following parameters

- sdk path is `/home/gufran/ADT2/sdk`
- ndk path is `/home/gufran/ADT2/android-ndk-r10e`

I have successfully generated `com_appxperts_firstndkapp_MainActivity.h` 
and also `MyJNI.c`. Now I would like generate the .so files with command

```
home/gufran/ADT2/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build.cmd
```

but its giving error

```
bash: home/gufran/ADT2/ndk/ndk-build.cmd: No such file or directory
```

Also tried

```
ndk-build.cmd
```

still error

```
ndk-build.cmd: command not found
```

Please note the NDK path is already set as

```
gufran@gufranKhurshid:~$ export NDK_HOME=home/gufran/ADT2/android-ndk-r10e
```

Comment: Ndk-build.  No "cmd" in expression

Comment: Can you please write the full command as  ndk-build without (.cmd ) is also not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Program "/ndk-build.cmd" is not found in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670855/error-program-ndk-build-cmd-is-not-found-in-path)

Answer (score 2):

> ndk-build.cmd command not found...

Put your tools on path. Also, you should export `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. See David Turner's answer to [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/qZjhOaynHXc/2ux2ZZdxy2MJ) on the NDK mailing list for the reasons.

Here's what my `.bash_profile` looks like on OS X. For Ubuntu, I believe you use `.profile`. Tools like `ndk-build` and `keytool` are on path:

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
export PS1="\h::\W$ "
...

# Android
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/opt/android-ndk-r10e
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/opt/android-sdk-macosx

export ANDROID_HOME=~/.android
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`

export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/":"$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools/":"$PATH"
```

Finally, run `ndk-build`, not `ndk-build.cmd`. I believe `ndk-build.cmd` is for Windows.

Comment: `ndk-build.cmd` is indeed for Windows. On Linux and Mac OS X, it's `ndk-build` that should be executed instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, locate your `jni` directory of your project in command-prompt if your `.c` files are available in it.Then just type command :

```
export NDK=enter your ndk path here  
export PATH=$NDK:$PATH
```

then, run command `ndk-build`. it will generate your `*.so` files in libs folder

Comment: I got this error  line 2: dirname: command not found
line 3: /Users/mdmaidul.islam/Documents/RD/NaussSample/build/ndk-build: No such file or directory. Please help me