# how to rebuild android jni C files in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am learning how to write an Android application that uses the NDK in order to call OpenCV C++ functions.

I am using Eclipse ADT version 22.3 and NDK R9C.

I have imported the hello-jni sample application from the NDK samples, and it compiles, builds, and runs on my Android device without problems.

However, when I make changes to the project's C source file and rebuild, the changes are not reflected in the build.  In fact, I can add a syntactic error into the C file and rebuild, but I get no errors.

Can someone please tell my why the JNI portion of my project is not getting recompiled?

I have tried to import the jni portion into Eclipse as a separate project.  But Eclipse does not seem to understand the makefiles in the jni directory.  It complains that the makefiles have no "all" targets (which they don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click on your project, can you select `Android Tools -> Add Native Support`?

Also, under `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build` is the `Use default build command` enabled?

Finally, `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Behaviour`, are the `Build (Incremental Build)` and `Clean` options selected?

Comment: When I checked for Add Native Support, Eclipse told me that my NDK location was incorrect.  I fixed that by following this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825534/set-build-path-in-eclipse-for-ndk-program, and now everything compiles correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  After fixing the NDK location, I still had to Import the project in the jni directory as a C/C++ application using Android GCC.

Comment: Actually you could just add ndk-build to auto build properties of Eclipse and that would handle all rebuilding process as you save the cpp files.

Comment: I tried all steps mentioned above .But still the changes are not reflected in android project.Can you resolve this problem?