# Issue Building tess-two library

Tags: java, android, linux, libraries

I am relatively new to android development and I have a problem building the project at the step 'ndk-build'.

```
Error - "Command not found".
```

I follow the build steps from [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two).
I am using a 64bit Kubuntu 14.10.

Comment: please add more info: exact command line, your `$PATH` environment variable and where `ndk-build`

Comment: @Micheled'Amico doest that help? http://i.imgur.com/zJeIIwy.png

Comment: The guide that you follow assume that you have already installed [android ndk](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Comment: I am pretty sure I have installed it, maybe it has something to do with the fact that Im on 64bit

Comment: On 64bit you should install the [64bit version](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin). If you already did it `ndk-build` should be somewhere in your system but not in the path. Maybe it is in your home in `android-ndk-*`. When you find it try to use `<real-path>/ndk-build` instead. If it works tell me that I will mark that question as a duplicate of [Set Build path in Eclipse for ndk program](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11825534/4101725) ... where I found the answer