# Can I develop OpenCV for Android without NDK?

Tags: opencv, intellij-idea, android-ndk

So I am developing using intelij and am having trouble setting up the NDK. I have looked for help online and searched other stack overflow questions but I cant seem to find anything helpful.

I know you can do somethings in opencv without the android NDK as I have managed to get some of the sample projects wokring but not all of them (assuming the ones that require the NDK).

So I was wondering what are the limitations to using opencv for android without the NDK. 
and if anyone has any links or guidance on how to setup the ndk for intellij would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

so finally figured it out!

You need the NDK for any native application bits, from what I have gathered this is recommended as the native camera features work faster and are more accurate, mainly because opencv was originally developed in c/c++.

Installing and setting up the NDK is really straight forward.

I managed to do it in around 20 seconds after reading this link =)

NOTE: I am using intellij and ubuntu and it worked (although it says 4 eclipse works for intellij too!)

[How to install and Build NDK with eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407224/how-to-install-and-build-ndk-with-eclipse?rq=1)

Comment: Does it really worth to use NDK for non-native functions of OpenCV? Is the speed and accuracy changing noticeable? cause i'm using Intellij IDEA which doesn't support NDK :(